# Log custom level to different file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to add a custom level to python logging and log this level and this level only to a specific file. I would also like to add this logger to the root logger so I won't have to get the logger every time.

I managed to do the following:

```
DEBUG_LEVELV_NUM = 60
logging.addLevelName(DEBUG_LEVELV_NUM, "DEBUGV")

actionLogger = logging.FileHandler(filename='ImportantActions.log')
actionLogger.setLevel(DEBUG_LEVELV_NUM)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
actionLogger.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(actionLogger)

logging.log(60, "Testing")
```

This does work, however I would like to avoid the `logging.info(60,`.

Is it possiable to add an API to the logging module, for example `logging.important_message()` and it will automatically log this level to ImportantActions.log?

Comment: I'm assuming `important_message` doesn't exists. So either you create a wrapper function that's called `def important_message` which simply calls `logging.log(60, msg)` or you try to insert that function into the `logging` class. The second option being not the recommended one. The last option would be to submit a feature request to the maintainer of that module. What you could do is do `logging.__dict__['important_message'] = important_function`. That way you can insert functions into the class but you'd still have to create the function you're pointing to. And you'd do this early in the code

Comment: I have a lot of modules in the project so I wouldn't like to import important_message in every one of them. How do you use this function after inserting it to `logging.__dict__['important_message']`?

Comment: Not sure that such a "insert" would work across multiple python files, in which case. You're better off creating your own wrapper function that all the modules can import. call it `mylogger.py` and import your function there. You can also do the `logging.__dict__` insert there if you really want to use the custom function.